# Mapping image onto 3D face mesh

Tags: 3d, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, iphone-x

I am using the iPhone X and `ARFaceKit` to capture the user's face. The goal is to texture the face mesh with the user's image.

I'm only looking at a single frame (an `ARFrame`) from the `AR` session.
From `ARFaceGeometry`, I have a set of vertices that describe the face.
I make a jpeg representation of the current frame's `capturedImage`.

I then want to find the texture coordinates that map the created jpeg onto the mesh vertices. I want to:

1. map the vertices from model space to world space;
2. map the vertices from world space to camera space;
3. divide by image dimensions to get pixel coordinates for the texture.

   let geometry: ARFaceGeometry = contentUpdater.faceGeometry!
   let theCamera = session.currentFrame?.camera

   let theFaceAnchor: SCNNode = contentUpdater.faceNode
   let anchorTransform = float4x4((theFaceAnchor?.transform)!)

   for index in 0..<totalVertices {
   let vertex = geometry.vertices[index]

   ```
    // Step 1: Model space to world space, using the anchor's transform
    let vertex4 = float4(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z, 1.0)
    let worldSpace = anchorTransform * vertex4

    // Step 2: World space to camera space
    let world3 = float3(worldSpace.x, worldSpace.y, worldSpace.z)
    let projectedPt = theCamera?.projectPoint(world3, orientation: .landscapeRight, viewportSize: (theCamera?.imageResolution)!)

    // Step 3: Divide by image width/height to get pixel coordinates
    if (projectedPt != nil) {
        let vtx = projectedPt!.x / (theCamera?.imageResolution.width)!
        let vty = projectedPt!.y / (theCamera?.imageResolution.height)!
        textureVs += "vt \(vtx) \(vty)\n"
    }
   ```

   }

This is not working, but instead gets me a very funky looking face! Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I assume camera space goes from -x to x. Texture space normally goes from 0 to 1. So you might need to add half the image Resolution to move the uper left pixel to 0,0

Comment: This is likely true, @Omni, and I have experimented with that, but there seems to be something more intrinsically wrong with my approach.

Comment: Did you ever found the solution?

Comment: Did you ever found the solution??

Comment: Did you ever found the solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi @coco! Are you able to get "map the vertices from world space to camera space" using the Tracking and Visualizing Faces documentation?

Comment: I have not tried for a while, @swiftlearneer

Answer (score 6):

Texturing the face mesh with the user's image is now available in the [Face-Based sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face-based_ar_experiences) published by Apple (section **Map Camera Video onto 3D Face Geometry**).

One can map camera video onto 3D Face Geometry using this following shader modifier.

```
// Transform the vertex to the camera coordinate system.
float4 vertexCamera = scn_node.modelViewTransform * _geometry.position;

// Camera projection and perspective divide to get normalized viewport coordinates (clip space).
float4 vertexClipSpace = scn_frame.projectionTransform * vertexCamera;
vertexClipSpace /= vertexClipSpace.w;

// XY in clip space is [-1,1]x[-1,1], so adjust to UV texture coordinates: [0,1]x[0,1].
// Image coordinates are Y-flipped (upper-left origin).
float4 vertexImageSpace = float4(vertexClipSpace.xy * 0.5 + 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
vertexImageSpace.y = 1.0 - vertexImageSpace.y;

// Apply ARKit's display transform (device orientation * front-facing camera flip).
float4 transformedVertex = displayTransform * vertexImageSpace;

// Output as texture coordinates for use in later rendering stages.
_geometry.texcoords[0] = transformedVertex.xy;
```

Comment: Hi Oliver! If you know how to use this code for 3D to 2D conversion?

Answer (score 1):

> **For proper UV mapping you need to use [ARSCNFaceGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnfacegeometry) class instead of [ARFaceGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfacegeometry) class you're using in your code**.

`ARSCNFaceGeometry` is a SceneKit's representation of face topology for use with face information provided by an `ARSession`. It's used for a quick visualization of face geometry using SceneKit's rendering engine.

`ARSCNFaceGeometry` class is a subclass of `SCNGeometry` that wraps the mesh data provided by the `ARFaceGeometry` class. You can use `ARSCNFaceGeometry` to quickly and easily visualize face topology and facial expressions provided by ARKit in a SceneKit view.

But `ARSCNFaceGeometry` is available only in SceneKit views or renderers that use Metal. ***This class is not supported for OpenGL-based SceneKit rendering***.

Answer (score 0):

The start point is different:

[image: Start point is different]

Apply the following changes to your code:

```
//let vty = projectedPt!.y / (theCamera?.imageResolution.height)!
let vty = ((theCamera?.imageResolution.height)! - projectedPt!.y) / (theCamera?.imageResolution.height)!
```

You can get Normal Face.